# Postman - I want to check a value to be inside an array

Tags: javascript, postman, assertion

I am writing a postman test in JavaScript to assert the scenario below.
I have an id `1111` and the response returns an array of ids. I want to write a test to match 1111 to be in one of the ids in the array.

I have tried to use the include function i.e.

```
pm.test("The response contains a valid id in the response", function() { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.results[0].totalId.children).to.include("1111");
});
```

---

```
{
    "totalId": "0000",
    "children": [{
            "id": "888"
        },
        {
            "id": "3323"
        },
        {
            "id": "1111"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggest.

Comment: So what's wrong? Your assert will fail, because have `111` and not `1111`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, however, the point is, that `1111` can be anywhere in that structure, not just in [2]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to check the value from the array `children`, hence, you should not use the `.totalId.children`, instead you have to do is `jsonData.results[0].children`.

As you trying to check the value from the object of an array, you need add custom JavaScript logic to check the values of `id` param.

Here is the function you can use in your test script.

```
function _isContains(json, keyname, value) {
return Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        return typeof json[key] === 'object' ? 
        _isContains(json[key], keyname, value) : key === keyname && json[key] === value;
    });
}
```

The function `_isContains` checks the value and key name for the each object from the array.

Now you can pass needed input to the function in your test case.

```
pm.test("The response contains a valid id in the response", function () {
    pm.expect(_isContains(jsonData.children, "id" ,"1111")).to.be.true;
});
```

This will check from the array of the object with the key `id` and value `1111`, if it's available then it will returns true, otherwise returns false.

---

**Final Test Script**

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test("The response contains a valid id in the response", function () {
    pm.expect(_isContains(jsonData.children, "id" ,"1111")).to.be.true;
});

function _isContains(json, keyname, value) {
 return Object.keys(json).some(key => {
        return typeof json[key] === 'object' ? 
        _isContains(json[key], keyname, value) : key === keyname && json[key] === value;
    });
}
```

Comment: How to extend the function if totalID is also an Array?

Comment: Not sure what you meant @Alka haven't touched `totalId` in the request. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My question : Will this function work in below case too  {
    "total": {
 "ID":"0000",
 "type":[{
 "typeID":1,
    "children": [{
            "id": "888"
        },
        {
            "id": "3323"
        },
        {
            "id": "1111"
        }
    ]
} ,
{
 "typeID":2,
    "children": [{
            "id": "8882"
        },
        {
            "id": "33232"
        },
        {
            "id": "11112"
        }
    ]
}
]
}
}

Comment: @Alka I don't think the answer will applicable to the JSON you provided, need some modification.

Answer (score 6):

A even simpler solution could be :

```
const child = jsonData.results[0].totalId.children.find(c => c.id === "1111");
pm.expect(child).exist;
```

The advantage of this method is that you can easily extend your tests suite to verify extended keys/values (like stated in the example of @Ajeet Shah) :

```
pm.expect(child.value).is.not.null;
```

Note : The assumption is that only one item of the array should have the id "1111". Indeed the find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code, children is a sibling of totalId, not a child.

I would do it like this:

```
pm.test("The response contains a valid id in the response", function () { 
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var ids = jsonData.children.map((i) => i.id);
    pm.expect(ids.includes('1111')).to.eql(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Justinas mentioned you have to check your id it is "111" and you are checking for "1111".Also you have to changet the structure of JSON you are missing "[" in array.

```
 {"totalId":"0000",
   "children": [
     {
     "id": "888"
     },
     {
     "id": "3323"
     },
     {
     "id": "111"
      }
     ]
  }
```

And the most Importaint thing that your test code should be changed to this:

```
pm.test("The response contains a valid id in the response", function () { pm.expect(jsonData.results[0].totalId.children[2]).to.eql("111"); });
```

Comment: Hi, jsonData.results[0].totalId.children[2] - the value could be at be at any level not just at [2].

Comment: With updated info my answer is not Full.You can follow what 'Div" wrote.You can mark his answer as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON object contains `null` values, the `_isContains` function needs a small modification: `&& json[key] !== null`:

```json
{
  "totalId":"0000",
  "children": [
  {
    "id": "888",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "id": "3323",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "id": "111",
    "value": null
   }
  ]
}
```

```js
function _isContains(json, keyname, value) {
  return Object.keys(json).some(key => {
      return typeof json[key] === 'object' && json[key] !== null ? 
      _isContains(json[key], keyname, value) : key === keyname && json[key] === value;
  });
}
```